# Access qnx network via android in pc

Tags: android, networking, qnx, hypervisor

The environment is SA8155, qnx hypervisor create two qvm, one is qnx 7.0 and one is android

Note: Android have already wifi, so we can access the wlan0 of Android in pc eth0 and they have common gateway 10.50.210.254

```
qnx:vp0 161.0.0.2 
android：vir0  161.0.0.1  
android：wlan0:10.50.210.94
pc: eth0: 10.50.210.192
```

Note 1：vir0 and vp0 can ping each other

Note 2: eth0 和wlan0 can ping each other

I want to use Android wlan0 as a bridge，how to access vp0 of qnx by eth0 of pc?

Comment: android dev
1、iptables -F 
2、iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 161.0.0.2:22 

qnx dev
# pfctl -si 

# pfctl -d 
pf disabled

pc dev
ssh root@10.50.210.94 will success!!!!